# Check for multiple values in array object - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following :

```
$scope.Items = [{"ItemId": 1, "ItemName":"Test1"}, {"ItemId": 2, "ItemName":"Test2"}, {"ItemId": 3, "ItemName":"Test3"}];
```

If I wish to check if ItemId 1 AND ItemId 2 exist within this, what would be the best approach for it? I believe the `indexOf` property should work, but how can it be used to check if a particular attribute value of the object exists within the array?

Comment: Try `Array.find` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Any idea how I could add the value of "ItemId" within the find() function?

Comment: Please refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use like also

```
$scope.firstitem=false;
$scope.seconditem=false;
angular.forEach($scope.Items, function (value, key) {
            if (value.ItemId== 1) { $scope.firstitem=true; }
            if (value.ItemId== 2) { $scope.seconditem=true; }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use find function like this to find by property you want.

```
var inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

function findCherries(fruit) { 
    return fruit.name === 'cherries';
}

console.log(inventory.find(findCherries)); 
// { name: 'cherries', quantity: 5 }
```

If you wish to filter (i.e , find multiple values.) you can use the `filter` function like this:

```
var arr = [
  { id: 15 },
  { id: -1 },
  { id: 0 },
  { id: 3 },
  { id: 12.2 },
  { },
  { id: null },
  { id: NaN },
  { id: 'undefined' }
];

var invalidEntries = 0;

function filterByID(obj) {
  if (obj.id !== undefined && typeof(obj.id) === 'number' && !isNaN(obj.id)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    invalidEntries++;
    return false;
  }
}

var arrByID = arr.filter(filterByID);

console.log('Filtered Array\n', arrByID); 
// Filtered Array
// [{ id: 15 }, { id: -1 }, { id: 0 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 12.2 }]

console.log('Number of Invalid Entries = ', invalidEntries); 
// Number of Invalid Entries = 4
```

Ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 2):

You could use [lodash](https://lodash.com)'s [`_.some()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#some) operator

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var Items = [{"ItemId": 1, "ItemName":"Test1"}, {"ItemId": 2, "ItemName":"Test2"}, {"ItemId": 3, "ItemName":"Test3"}];

var hasItem1 = _.some(Items,  ["ItemId", 1]);
var hasItem2 = _.some(Items,  ["ItemId", 2]);

console.log ("hasItem1 = "+hasItem1);
console.log ("hasItem2 = "+hasItem2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use lodash's _.findIndex() operator

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var Items = [{"ItemId": 1, "ItemName":"Test1"}, {"ItemId": 2, "ItemName":"Test2"}, {"ItemId": 3, "ItemName":"Test3"}];

var hasItem1 = false;
var hasItem2 = false;
if(_.findIndex(Items, {ItemId : 1}) != -1) { hasItem1 = true; }
if(_.findIndex(Items, {ItemId : 2}) != -1) { hasItem2 = true; }

console.log ("hasItem1 = "+hasItem1);
console.log ("hasItem2 = "+hasItem2);
```